# Process of interaction of two particles from the point of view of quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, interactions

I have not opened the textbook for a long time and may have forgotten something, but, as far as I remember, to describe the interaction of two particles it is necessary to integrate this process throughout the entire space-time. The question relates specifically to time. If I am not mistaken, in quantum mechanics there is no such concept "particles began to interact at time $t_0$", and the interaction is described as an integral over the entire time with different amplitudes for different $t$. Do I remember correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantum mechanics does not predict  interactions the same way that classical mechanics does. There are no trajectories for particles to interact. In QM the integration is necessary because the prediction is a probability curve for the interaction to occur at (x,y,z,t). [Probabilities](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/probas.html) have to integrate to 1 over all the available phase space , by definition.

Comment: That is, I remember correctly. Thank you!

Comment: "In QM the integration is necessary because the prediction is a probability curve for the interaction to occur at (x,y,z,t).".
@anna v Not very correct. The process of interaction of quantum particles is not probabilistic. Probabilities appear only when a macroscopic observer, using a macroscopic device, intervenes in the unitary evolution of a unified quantum system, transforming its pure state into a mixed one. That's when the probabilities appear.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress    I learned the $Ψ^*Ψ$ gives the probability, is part of the postulates of quantum mechanics, and I expect that even a pure $Ψ$ state does that.?

Comment: @annav Ψ does not give probability. The probability gives | Ψ | ^ 2. There is a huge difference between them. When you take a measurement, you change the system uncontrollably, and the only information is the probabilities. To summarize, probabilities are an artifact of the relationship between an intelligent observer and the information that can be obtained from a quantum system. At least that's what the Copenhagen Interpretation says.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress  we cannot agree, As an experimentalist for me Ψ  is a mathematial tool, just as a parabola is a mathematical tool for newtonian interactions. I measure probabilities . There are no intelligent observers in the interaction regions of proton hitting proton in the LHC and detectors recording electronically the results.

Comment: @annavOf course, in the end it is the calculations of probability and experimental observation that are important. But we are also talking about describing a system before probabilities and observation appear. And in these descriptions, probabilities do not appear. Quantum mechanics does not say that particles interact with each other probabilistically. She says that any observation with a macroscopic instrument is probabilistic. The Bourne Rule is about observation only.